# How to use jq to convert json to csv from a complex json data

Tags: arrays, json, csv, jq

I'm new in using jq tool.
I have a json file extracted from mongodb database to be formatted into csv:

**json data in foo.json**

```
{
    "_id" : "8888888888",
    "unitcode" : "Unit123",
    "purpose" : "Validate",
    "request" : {
        "url" : "Brocolli",
        "method" : "UPDATED",
        "body" : {
            "bonds" : [
                {
                    "bondDesc" : "bondDesc1",
                    "priorPriceBid" : 100,
                    "priorPriceOffer" : 101,
                    "priorYieldBid" : 6.555,
                    "priorYieldOffer" : 6.777,
                    "updatedPriceBid" : 691,
                    "updatedPriceOffer" : 169,
                    "updatedYieldBid" : 25.2345,
                    "updatedYieldOffer" : 25.9999
                },
                {
                    "bondDesc" : "bondDesc2",
                    "priorPriceBid" : 200,
                    "priorPriceOffer" : 201,
                    "priorYieldBid" : 2.555,
                    "priorYieldOffer" : 2.777,
                    "updatedPriceBid" : 791,
                    "updatedPriceOffer" : 269,
                    "updatedYieldBid" : 35.2345,
                    "updatedYieldOffer" : 35.9999
                }
            ]
        },
        "source" : "Cloud",
        "isMultipleBond" : true
    },
    "response" : {
        "statusCode" : 200
    }
}
```

**Desired output:**

```
"UPDATED","Brocolli","bondDesc1",100,101,6.555,6.777,691,169,25.2345,25.9999
"UPDATED","Brocolli","bondDesc2",200,201,2.555,2.777,791,269,35.2345,35.9999
```

**I already tried the following commands:**

1. first try

   ```
   jq -r '[.request.method, .request.url] | @csv'  foo.json
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   "bondDesc1",100
   ```
2. next try

   ```
   jq -r ' .request.body.bonds[] | [.bondDesc, .priorPriceBid, .priorPriceOffer, .priorYieldBid, .priorYieldOffer, .updatedPriceBid, .updatedPriceOffer, .updatedYieldBid, .updatedYieldOffer] | @csv' foo.json
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   "bondDesc1",100,101,6.555,6.777,691,169,25.2345,25.9999
   "bondDesc2",200,201,2.555,2.777,791,269,35.2345,35.9999
   ```
3. But I can't figure out on how to combine them, it just gave me an error:

   ```
   jq -r ' [.request.method, .request.url], .request.body.bonds[] | [.bondDesc, .priorPriceBid, .priorPriceOffer, .priorYieldBid, .priorYieldOffer, .updatedPriceBid, .updatedPriceOffer, .updatedYieldBid, .updatedYieldOffer] | @csv' foo.json
   ```

   **Result:**

   ```
   jq: error (at foo.json:40): Cannot index array with string "bondDesc"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Since the fields you want are at varying depths and in arrays, typical strategy is to collect the values you want at each level expanding any array separately then combine them all.

Assuming you want the values in file order, you could just grab all values from the bond objects.

```
.request | [.method, .url] + (.body.bonds[] | [.[]]) | @csv
```

Though in general, you probably will want to explicitly pick out the values you want.

```
.request | [.method, .url] + (.body.bonds[] | [
  .bondDesc,
  .priorPriceBid,
  .priorPriceOffer,
  .priorYieldBid,
  .priorYieldOffer,
  .updatedPriceBid,
  .updatedPriceOffer,
  .updatedYieldBid,
  .updatedYieldOffer
]) | @csv
```

You had the right idea, but the parentheses around the expansion of the `bonds` array is important.

[jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/zPQqPYWmuZY)

Answer (score 1):

As @Jeff_Mercado mentioned, you could potentially go with

```
.request | [.method, .url] + (.body.bonds[] | [.[]]) | @csv
```

but that assumes the ordering of keys within the objects is the same.
Even if you believe that to be the case, it would be wise to adopt a more robust solution.  Listing the keys would be one way to go, but that is tedious and not robust w.r.t. the addition or deletion of keys in the future.

Assuming you want all the values corresponding to the keys in the first .bonds object, you could use the following:

```
.request
| (.body.bonds[0] | keys_unsorted) as $keys
| [.method, .url] + (.body.bonds[] | [.[$keys[]]])
| @csv
```